# Doctrine 2 entity caching while persisting

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am having an issue with Doctrine 2 and can not find a solution for it. It seems that when persisting an entity (and flushing it). When trying to search for it in DB using the assigned id while within the same PHP process doctrine is giving me the cached version of the entity instead of building a proper one with all correct relations. My problem with that is that my entity has some Many to many or many to one connections and if i get the the cached version all those properties come back as null instead of an instance of \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection.
Is there any way I can force doctrine to generate or update my entity to assign all those connections, or at least force it to serch for that entity insead of giving it to me from cache?

As requested examples:

```
class A extends AbstractDoctrineEntity {

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */    
protected $id;

/**
 * @var \Core\Entity\B
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Core\Entity\B")
 */
protected $relationB;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Core\Entity\C", inversedBy="relationA", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 *
 */
protected $relationC;

//getters and setters
}


class B extends AbstractDoctrineEntity {

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */    
protected $id;

/**
 * @var \Core\Entity\A
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Core\Entity\A")
 */
protected $relationA;

//getters and setters
}

class B extends AbstractDoctrineEntity {

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */    
protected $id;

/**
 * @var \Core\Entity\A
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Core\Entity\A", mappedBy="realtionC", cascade={"persist", "remove")
 */
protected $relationA;

//getters and setters
}

// Service

class SomeService implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface, MultiRepositoryServiceInterface {
use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait, MultiRepositoryServiceTrait;

public function createA(\Core\Entity\B $b) {
    $a = new \Core\Entity\A();
    $a->setB($b);
    $this->getRepository('a')->persist($a); // gets entity manager persists entity $a and flushes

    return $a;
    /**
     * returns an object
     * a = {
     *   id = 2,
     *   relationB = Core\Entity\B,
     *   ralationC = null,
     */
       }

}

public function getA($id){
    $a = $this->getRepository('a')->persist($a); // retrieves object manager and queries by id;

    return $a;
    //**
     * returns an object
     * a = {
     *   id = 2,
     *   relationB = Core\Entity\B,
     *   ralationC = \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection,  //which is an empty collection prototype and exactly what i need to retrieve in the first case when persisting the entity.
     *   }
     */

}
}
```

EDIT:
 Found a solution, this may not be the nicest way to do this, so if someone knows a better way please update, but for now it works:

```
-----
public function createA(\Core\Entity\B $b) {
    $a = new \Core\Entity\A();
    $a->setB($b);
    $this->getRepository('a')->persist($a); // gets entity manager persists entity $a and flushes
    $this->getRepository('a')->detatch($a); // removes entity from management

    return $this->getRepository('a')->find($a->getId());
    /**
     * returns an object
     * a = {
     *   id = 2,
     *   relationB = Core\Entity\B,
     *   ralationC = \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection,
     */
       }

}
----
```

This has a downside of re-querying after detachment and has a negative performance impact. If someone knows of a better solution it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you add the entity source? If  you set the associated properties to Collection in the entitity construct they should be an empty Collection - I think..

Comment: If it comes without relations then I would say your object model is not correct... Share code if you want more help.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to make sure people can actually answer your question.

Comment: I will update the question but the code is not relevant here and being smug does not make you more right Wilt. The models are correct because when performing a query on something that is allready saved to DB in another process all relations are built correctly. The problem is only when querying in the same process as persisting (read the question fully please.